# Why does ADS-B altitude from multiple landed planes vary so much from one plane to another?

Tags: landing, runways, altitude, ads-b, flight-tracking

When viewing ADS-B data from sites like FlightAware and Flightradar24 (and also from a personal antenna), the landed altitudes vary greatly from one aircraft to another.  **What accounts for this variance?**

For example, given a runway at 500 ft. elevation above sea level, 3 aircraft landing within a couple of minutes of each other show landed altitudes of 500 ft., 600 ft., and 750 ft. (AMSL)

I should also point out that the ADS-B data points are the same across the tracking websites and personal antenna, and the lat/lon values show landed positions - so there is no variance between the tracking sites.

Comment: Just as a reference, the operative FAR is [14 CFR § 91.217](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.217) which states that the altitude transmitted must be referenced to 29.92 inhg and that ads-b and mode c must share a data source. So I'm not sure what would account for the discrepancy.

Comment: I was going to say perhaps the messages aren't that frequent - but ADSB transmits every second (https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/afx/afs/afs400/afs410/ads-b) ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The aircraft do not send out altitude when they are on the ground.

On the ground, aircraft send out the surface messages, which combine position, speed and heading.

The airborne message formats combine position and pressure altitude in one message, and speed vector and geometric altitude in another.

The lowest altitude you see is the last altitude decoded by the receiver before the aircraft touched down. Unless the receiver has very good line of sight to the final approach and touchdown area, and is not suffering from garbling (overlapping of messages received from various aircraft at the same time), the last altitude you will may be actually be quite high above the runway.

Comment: However the planes do transmit their position while on ground, so shouldn't the altitude also be receivable all the way untill the system shutoff? In case the altitude transmission stops with weight on wheels event, last transmission should be very close to field elevation (ambient pressure taken in account?).

Comment: @Jpe61 the transmission of altitude seizes with WoW. The last altitude transmitted is typically at or 25ft above the field (after applying QNH correction). But transmitted does not equal received. At low altitude, there is often not a direct line of sight between the transmitting antenna and the receiver antenna. Also, messages get lost due to collision with other messages being received at the same time.

Comment: But how does the ground position keep updating?

Comment: I've seen "0" on FlightRadar24 for some recently-landed planes where field elevation is approx 1300' -- ?

Comment: @Jpe61 Ground position keeps update through multipath (reflections), diffraction etc. but not at a rate of 1/seconds. Flight radar 24 is very good at connecting the dots with lines, but really on many airports the surface tracks are not that frequently updated. 10 second between updates would already result in at >100ft error at 700 fpm descent rate, but is barely visible in the ground track.

Comment: @quietflyer pressure altitude can be quite different from actual AMSL value if  QNH is far from 1013.25 / 29.92

Comment: @Jpe61 to substantiate the comment about multipath and diffraction: for a long time I operated and ADS-B receiver in an apartment in a city centre. The antenna was mounted outside a window. I could receive ground positions form the local airport at a few very specific locations: these were reflections from a single high rise building about 2km away in the general direct of the airport. At certain weather conditions (strong inversion layer) I could receive messages from the surface of a big international airport 50 km away with a probability of about 1/100 per transmitted message.

Comment: Thanks @DeltaLima that makes sense 

Comment: I often receive ground messages on my receiver, and also many that are not, so these other altitudes must be just prior to landing. That makes sense, but it's still strange to see the variance of a couple hundred feet in similar positions.  But is my understanding correct that all ADS-B out is calibrated to 29.92 and thus all systems "should" report similar altitudes "if" we could see them all at the same exact position spatially?

Comment: Also don't forget the ADSB receivers aren't located perfectly, so it's likely planes are going out of reception before landing.

Answer (score 1):

Aircraft DO transmit altitude while on the ground... look at the ADSB data that comes from the aircraft.  If the data hasn't been edited, in the "alt" column you can see clearly altitude IS being transmitted even though the aircraft is on the ground and displaying GND status. The data can also include the corrected altitude and the pilot entered correction pressure that is supposed to yield the correct height above sea level. That resultant varies quite a bit also.

As to why there are altitude variations among aircraft simultaneously on the ground at the same time... varying typically about 200 feet, boggles the mind. It's hard to imagine that a digitally monitored analogue device that is supposed to be calibrated (once a year?), could get so out of whack. But, there's another contributing factor.

Older and less expensive transponders output altitude data in 100 foot increments (newer are 25 ft and a few at 10 ft resolution); this means that when the first pulse of 100 ft altitude appears, you are probably only about 51 feet when the transponder transmits the message.  This step resolution transmission of altitude is usually smoothed by some method of averaging. But what do you do when an aircraft has the right altimeter setting but displays -100 feet when you're at 16 feet above sea level?  And then you move to another aircraft on the ground 16 ft above sea level and it too has the correct altimeter setting but it reads 50 feet?

For municipal and County owned airports, they may opt to buy a service like WebTrak from Envirosuite so aircraft can be accurately tracked locally.  But, in our area, Envirosuite/WebTrak solves the above problem by wiping out all ground data and substituting one of two values that correspond with the elevation of the airport (Geodetic or GPS).  But one sin leads to another.

This clean up means that altitude data has to be 'adjusted' all the way up to about 800 feet. This process erases all the altitude differences of aircraft on the ground.  I'm currently looking for data on normal variations of altimeters.  I guess we could blame it on Cro-Magnon technology of pressure cans moving a spring, but what are the alternatives?  Radar altimeters are very expensive.  GPS has satellite time delays and depends on ellipsoids and Geoids, none of which are universally accepted.  That still leaves us without a satisfying explanation.